# How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, package.json

No error when I entered **npm run dev** to edit the code, but can not build/export it.

Here is the **ERROR** that shown on the Terminal when I entered **npm run build**

```
> @landing/015-next@0.0.1 postbuild C:\Users\Han\Desktop\andamilo\agency-alpha-next
> next-sitemap

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @landing/015-next@0.0.1 postbuild: `next-sitemap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @landing/015-next@0.0.1 postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-30T03_47_34_736Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "@landing/015-next",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "serve": "next start",
    "export": "next export",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^2.9.5",
    "next": "^10.0.3",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "polished": "^4.0.5",
    "rc-drawer": "^4.1.0",
    "rc-tabs": "^11.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.2.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-stickynode": "^3.0.4",
    "swiper": "^6.3.5",
    "theme-ui": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.1.6"
  }
}
```

I have deleted cache and re-install npm, but it is not working.
Is there alternative way to resolve this error?

best regards,

Comment: have you tried to remove `.next` folder?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does your `next-sitemap.js` file look like?

Comment: There is no next-sitemap.js, but I can see the sitemap.xml which is included in this template. and it looks like this, 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://leerob.iosrc//index</loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```